# YUI Editor hiding the title bar?

Tags: editor, yui

Is it possible to hide the title bar created by the YUI editor? I want to have the editor rendered in a  tag without the titlebar and unable to collapse the toolbar.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS to hide the titlebar.

```
#editor-container .yui-toolbar-titlebar {
 display: none;
}
```

#editor-container should be the id of the containing div. For more examples, check out the [skinning editor example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/skinning_editor.html) from the YUI team.

Comment: Short solution, maybe inelegant.

Answer (score 2):

You can also remove  the `titlebar: 'Text Editing Tools',` line from the configuration, and set collapse to false:

```
{
  handleSubmit: true,
  autoHeight: false,
  dompath: false,
  collapse: false,
  toolbar: {
    collapse: false,
    draggable: false,
    buttonType: 'advanced',
    buttons: [
        { group: 'textstyle',
            buttons: [
                { type: 'push', label: 'Bold CTRL + SHIFT + B', value: 'bold' },
                { type: 'push', label: 'Italic CTRL + SHIFT + I', value: 'italic' },
                { type: 'push', label: 'Underline CTRL + SHIFT + U', value: 'underline' },
            ]
        },             
        { type: 'separator' },
        { group: 'indentlist',
            buttons: [
                { type: 'push', label: 'Indent', value: 'indent', disabled: true },
                { type: 'push', label: 'Outdent', value: 'outdent', disabled: true },
                { type: 'push', label: 'Create an Unordered List', value: 'insertunorderedlist' },
                { type: 'push', label: 'Create an Ordered List', value: 'insertorderedlist' }
            ]
        }        
    ]
  }
}
```